# UPPER function is not working properly on O umlaut characters in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

Please note that I have a postgres database as : -

```
   Name    |   Owner    | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |     Access privileges
-----------+------------+----------+-------------+-------------+----------------------------
 my_db     | admin_user | UTF8     | de_DE.UTF-8 | C           | =Tc/admin_user            +
           |            |          |             |             | admin_user=CTc/admin_user +
           |            |          |             |             | my_readonly=c/admin_user
```

UPPER function is not working properly on O umlaut characters in this database.
Please advice if there is any settings that can be  the issue.

Comment: [works for me](https://dbfiddle.uk/P2Su1oCZ)

Comment: Please can you share : show lc_ctype;
show lc_collate; Encoding ?

Answer (score 1):

What determines the rules about what is a number or a letter; or the correspondence of small to big letters is `LC_CTYPE`*. You need it to be something like `de_DE.UTF-8` in order to do UPPER for such letters. You have `C` at the moment.

When creating a DB, Postgres takes these settings from the environment variables in operating system. But you can override them at that point.

*I read CTYPE as Character TYPE